# Stanford_CoreNLP plugin for gate

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gate

I'm searching a `Stanford_CoreNLP plugin` with `Stanford NER`(not `StanfordParser` or `StandfordPOSTagger`) for `GATE` (General Architecture for Text Engineering). I found some information about the plugin [here](https://gate.ac.uk/gate/doc/plugins.html#Stanford_CoreNLP). But I couldn't find it integrated with `GATE` (version 8) by default. I also tried to find a link to download the plugin, but couldn't find...

Does anyone has a clue about how to activate it or from where to download it?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Yep, looks like it's missing from the distribution. Probably best to talk to the GATE people about this (if you haven't already..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon mentioned, somehow the Stanford_CoreNLP plugin was left out of the most recent release package of GATE. However, it is included in the daily snapshots built by their Jenkins server. You can download those here:

http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/

Unfortunately, there is no pre-built .gapp file for Stanford NER included with the GATE plugin. This means it isn't as simple as loading an application file to run Stanford NER inside GATE -- there's quite a bit more configuration involved. You might be able to build a custom .gapp file of your own, but in the meantime, the NER.java file in the source code for the Stanford NER plugin will help you get started running it inside GATE:

http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/Stanford_CoreNLP/src/gate/stanford/NER.java