# How to get the stanford NER plugin working with GATE?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gate

I am new to GATE (version 8.0) and trying to get the Stanford NER working as part of the processing pipeline.

If I just do a search for Stanford in the plugins I don't see it:

[image]

I'm finding conflicting information online about how to add it in.

I know that there is [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/Stanford_CoreNLP/src/gate/stanford/NER.java) plugin file. I also see that there is a StanfordNER plugin [listed](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch23.html#sec:misc:creole:stanford) in the GATE docs. I saw this on a stanford [mailing list](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2012-March/001918.html). Plus I saw this old post from stackoverflow: [Stanford_CoreNLP plugin for gate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423778/stanford-corenlp-plugin-for-gate)

How do I get Stanford NER installed and working with GATE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am new to GATE (version 8.0)

The `Stanford_CoreNLP` plugin was introduced in June 2014, *after* the release of GATE version 8.0, so you need to download a more recent [nightly snapshot](http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/) build and install that instead.  In version 8.0 the Stanford POS tagger and parser were available as separate plugins (as you show in your screenshot) but the NER tools were not included at that point.

As a general rule, if you want to be sure you're looking at the correct version of the GATE user guide then you should access it via the "help" menu in GATE Developer.  The [user guide link](https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/) on the GATE website refers to the latest snapshot, not to a numbered release.

---

Edit June 2015: GATE Developer version 8.1 has now been released, which includes the `Stanford_CoreNLP` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You must load the Stanford CoreNLP plugin. Then, you have to create a new Processing Resource like that:

[image]

Then, you just have to include your PR in a pipeline. For example, here I replace the traditional NE Transducer by Stanford NER:

[image]

Finally, try it on a corpus and you'll have the NE annotation.

Comment: I don't see the stanford Ner in the list. How do I load it?

Comment: You just have to load the StanfordCore NLP plugin through Creole plugin manager. Then, you'll we see new PR in your list (Stanford NER included). Which version of GATE are you using ? If you're a new GATE user you can have a look to the GATE courses https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun14/ particularly this introduction https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-jun14/module-1-ie-and-eval/module-1-introduction-to-gui.pdf

Comment: I am using stable build 8.0. The folks from the mailing list say that Stanford Core NLP was not included in that release. So I guess I need to go to the nightly build? I downloaded that but don't know how to build it.

Comment: version 8.0 was the problem. I downloaded the latest build and ran it and now see Stanford Core NLP.

Comment: if you're ok with the answer you can accept the response